# Subtitles display in moview

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video downloaded from a link and also the `.srt` files for it. 
How can I show the subtitles?

They are not included with in the video, instead they are given as a separate url. 
From what I browsed so far `MPMoviePlayerController` wont support such kind of external subtitles but `AVPlayer` does. 
Can any one please suggest a solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement the subtitle thing yourself. So you first need to parse the .srt and then display UILabels with the text at the right time.

Look at this:
[How to display subtitles within MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212809/how-to-display-subtitles-within-mpmovieplayercontroller)